# Oracle stored procedure to return a list of ids

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to convert an sql stored procedure to oracle.  It's a very trivial procedure.  It just returns a list of ids from a table, which is very easy to do in sql.

**SQL**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tspInstalledLanguages]  
AS
BEGIN   
    SELECT language_id from languages
END
```

I'm a complete novice when it comes to oracle, and I've learned that it's not as straight forward as this.

I've tried the following:

**Oracle**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE tspInstalledLanguages
AS  
BEGIN
  SELECT LANGUAGE_ID FROM LANGUAGES;  
END;
```

With no luck.
I get a message that it's expecting `select into`

Answer (score 1):

[It is.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pl_sql_plsql_select_into_clause.htm)
Example:

```
DECLARE
  v_authName author.author_last_name%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT author_last_name
  INTO v_authName
  FROM author 
  WHERE author_key = 'A103';
  dbms_output.put_line('Name: '||v_authName);
END;
/
```

So using your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE tspInstalledLanguages
IS
v_language NUMBER; 
BEGIN
  SELECT LANGUAGE_ID 
  INTO v_language
  FROM LANGUAGES;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_language);
END;
/
```

Comment: Will this return the same result as the select statement?

Comment: Yep the `dbms_output` will shoot that output to the CLI or output window in SQL Dev.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it out.  It's being read into an ORM so the result needs to be a collection of rows exactly like the result of a select statement.

Comment: Use set serveroutput on; before the pls/sql block to make sure the output is sent to the CLI.

Comment: Can't speak much to the ORM side of it, TBH, but that is the way the procedure should look. You may have to build the procedure to return the values. If so just let me know and I'll rig it up or you can google 'oracle procedure return results'

Comment: Thanks.  I'll forward all this and try it out, and select the answer if it works out.

Comment: I just do it for the glory not the rep.